# MySQL unknown column ERROR

Tags: mysql

I am getting an unknown column in the applicant table when I try and execute this statement. I am trying to update this column consistent with the rest of the database.

```
  UPDATE APPLICANT SET totskills 
   = (SELECT count(sname) FROM SPOSSESSED 
   WHERE SPOSSESSED.anumber = APPLICANT.anumber);
```

I am new with using MySQL, is this because I need to be joining the applicant class? If so, how would it be written. Thank you

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Can you search if there is a column with the exact name as **SPOSSESSED.anumber** in your table , its seems that is not there that's why

Comment: the error is unknown column 'APPLICANT.anumber' in 'where' clause, both of these do exist